# In org-mode, how do I export to JIRA wiki markup?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

The org-mode Worg site, [org-export-generic](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-export-generic.html) , says that there is a wikipedia exporter. I tried to run it with `M-x org-export-generic` but i'm getting a 'Cannot open load file:org-export-generic' error.

I need to get my current .org file to export to a [Jira Wiki Markup](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=all) using export so I can put it on a JIRA description.

I'm using emacs24.3.1 on windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `org-contrib` packages are not included with Emacs -- you would need to download an org distribution and add the contrib packages to your load-path as described in the [Installation section](http://orgmode.org/manual/Installation.html#Installation) of the Org manual.

However, it looks like `org-export-generic` was removed from org-contrib a few years ago. You could experiment with `ox-confluence` (also part of org-contrib) as I believe the markup is the same for Confluence and Jira.

Comment: thanks for that, now i'm just facing a problem of the confluence exporter not handling slash \ is there a standard way to escape this characters for exporting?

Comment: What issue do you see with slashes? I'm using a somewhat modified version of ox-confluence and it seems to leave `\\` alone.

Comment: When I have a link description with a slash like for example [[http:www.google.com][googl\e.com]] orgmode takes care of the link and displays it as googl\e.com but when i export it with M-x org-confluence-export-as-confluence it'll error with something like "Wrong type argument: stringp, (latex-fragment....." I realised that it does handle \ on a normal body text, but it encounters that error on a link's description.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this do not transform exactly to JIRA Wiki markup format but to Confluence Wiki Markup, just use this function:

```
org-confluence-export-as-confluence is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
‘ox-confluence.el’.

(org-confluence-export-as-confluence &optional ASYNC SUBTREEP VISIBLE-ONLY
BODY-ONLY EXT-PLIST)

Export current buffer to a text buffer.

If narrowing is active in the current buffer, only export its
narrowed part.

If a region is active, export that region.

A non-nil optional argument ASYNC means the process should happen
asynchronously.  The resulting buffer should be accessible
through the ‘org-export-stack’ interface.

When optional argument SUBTREEP is non-nil, export the sub-tree
at point, extracting information from the headline properties
first.

When optional argument VISIBLE-ONLY is non-nil, don’t export
contents of hidden elements.

When optional argument BODY-ONLY is non-nil, strip title, table
of contents and footnote definitions from output.

EXT-PLIST, when provided, is a property list with external
parameters overriding Org default settings, but still inferior to
file-local settings.

Export is done in a buffer named "*Org CONFLUENCE Export*", which
will be displayed when ‘org-export-show-temporary-export-buffer’
is non-nil.

[back]
```

Afters installing the package [org-plus-contrib](https://orgmode.org/elpa/)

I use cask, so you cand add in your Cask File:

```
(source org)
           ...
(depends-on "org-plus-contrib")
```

Just open your org mode file and:

M-x org-confluence-export-as-confluence

This will export

[image: sample export]